# Master degree after getting a PhD degree

Tags: masters, biotechnology, masters-post-phd, materials-science

I completed my Ph.D. studies and was rewarded a Doctorate degree in Dental science, with a major in Biomaterials for odontology and orthopedic bone regeneration purposes. Although I like my field. I have always been interested in cancer treatment and fascinated by molecular and Biotechnology science, after searching here and there I am thinking to apply for an MSc in Molecular biology, Biotechnology, and Genetics. Is it okay to get a Master's degree after my Ph.D.?

The reasons that made me think about this besides my forever interest in this field, are that I am a one-year Ph.D. graduate now, and still I did not get a job offer, and also I did not get an opportunity to learn the programs and techniques for data science analysis such as (MATLAB, Python...etc)

Comment: What do you define by "okay"? Do you have a certain country in mind? Also, for your last paragraph: Can you clarify whether these are reasons for or against the master? I don't quite understand if you say "against the master because I'm longer without job" or "for the master because I learn programs". Are studies in your country paid by the state? Can you just enroll in a university or does someone needs to accept you?

Comment: You don't need to enroll in a masters program to learn a few tools like MATLAB or Python.

Comment: See also: [(How) Can I switch from field X to field Y after getting my PhD?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/187461/how-can-i-switch-from-field-x-to-field-y-after-getting-my-phd)